# Xcode, Interface Builder and StackView

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am following the tutorial here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html

Basicly you have 3 controls you have embedded in the stackview.

In the above control, they then show they drag in an image view and the stackview resizes automatically. Only in my case, it does not. And no matter how I fiddle with setings, I do not get anything that remotely works/looks like tthe tutorial.

If I drop the imageview in the stackview it takes 2/3 visual space. I need the stackview to resize itself larger. I have tried changing some options, but well, unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

In the stackview property "Distribution" choose "Fill equally" instead of "Fill" and the stackview will adjust automatically